# Font and Viewport libgdx

Tags: fonts, libgdx, viewport, scaling

I'm currently struggling a lot with FreeTypeFontGenerator from libgdx.

Here is my code :

```
public class FontTestScreen extends ScreenAdapter {
    private static final float WORLD_HEIGHT = 100;
    private static final int FONT_SIZE = (int) (WORLD_HEIGHT/10);

    private Viewport viewport;
    private SpriteBatch batch;
    private FreeTypeFontGenerator fontGenerator;
    private BitmapFont font;

    public FontTestScreen() {
        fontGenerator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("calibri.ttf"));
        batch = new SpriteBatch();
        /* Setting the viewport */
        viewport = new ExtendViewport(0, WORLD_HEIGHT);
        /* BitmapFont */
        FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
        parameter.size = FONT_SIZE;
        parameter.color = Color.BLACK;
        font = fontGenerator.generateFont(parameter);
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        viewport.update(width, height, true);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(viewport.getCamera().combined);
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        font.draw(batch, "Hello", WORLD_HEIGHT/2, WORLD_HEIGHT/2);
        batch.end();
    }

}
```

My problem is the following : 
If I correctly understood the viewport philosophy I should get rid of the notion of pixel. If my world has the meter for unit, well, instead of thinking with pixel I should use a viewport to set my world coordinates. In my example my world would be 100 meters high. I want to print a text whose size will be 10 meters. The problem is that the text is really pixelated and unreadable. If I change my world_height to 1000 instead of 10 and try to print my text with a size of 100 instead of 10 the text is not pixelated anymore.
This behaviour doesn't happen with textures ! Why do I have to struggle with that when only the ratio should be of importance ?

The more logical answer I found is that i'm doing it wrong. So please help me understanding the correct way of dealing with fonts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your viewport is in meters (or whatever) units. But FreeTypeFontGenerator uses pixels, because it's drawing pixels into a bitmap to create your font. So use the number of pixels tall you want your font to be.

In your case, since you want the font to be 1/10 the height of the screen:

```
private static final float FONT_SCREEN_HEIGHT_FRACTION = 1/10f;

//...
parameter.size = (int)(FONT_SCREEN_HEIGHT_FRACTION * Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Then scale the resulting font so it will be in your world units instead of pixel units:

```
font = fontGenerator.generateFont(parameter);
font.getData().setScale(WORLD_HEIGHT / Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

Comment: Yeah, okay. It really looks like a bypass though, not something we're supposed to do. Thank you.

Comment: That's because GUI's are generally done with pixels. It's an exception to the viewport philosophy, because GUI stuff looks better when it is pixel perfect. It keeps the edges of buttons and text crisper. But that is more work because you must keep multiple dpi versions of your assets. And if your text is not part of the GUI but rather moves around in the game "world" then the above is almost certainly what you should do.